# AppEngine Blobstore keeps returning 206 partial response

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I am having trouble getting the AppEngine Blobstore upload sample to work.  Looking further, I see that Blobstore.Send() always returns HTTP 206 "Partial response".

```
package blobstore_example

import (
        "html/template"
        "io"
        "net/http"

        "appengine"
        "appengine/blobstore"
)

func serveError(c appengine.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, err error) {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        io.WriteString(w, "Internal Server Error")
        c.Errorf("%v", err)
}

var rootTemplate = template.Must(template.New("root").Parse(rootTemplateHTML))

const rootTemplateHTML = `
<html><body>
<form action="{{.}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form></body></html>
`

func handleRoot(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        c := appengine.NewContext(r)
        uploadURL, err := blobstore.UploadURL(c, "/upload", nil)
        if err != nil {
                serveError(c, w, err)
                return
        }
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
        err = rootTemplate.Execute(w, uploadURL)
        if err != nil {
                c.Errorf("%v", err)
        }
}

func handleServe(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        blobstore.Send(w, appengine.BlobKey(r.FormValue("blobKey")))
}

func handleUpload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        c := appengine.NewContext(r)
        blobs, _, err := blobstore.ParseUpload(r)
        if err != nil {
                serveError(c, w, err)
                return
        }
        file := blobs["file"]
        if len(file) == 0 {
                c.Errorf("no file uploaded")
                http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
                return
        }
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/serve/?blobKey="+string(file[0].BlobKey), http.StatusFound)
}

func init() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", handleRoot)
        http.HandleFunc("/serve/", handleServe)
        http.HandleFunc("/upload", handleUpload)
}
```

Firefox 32 does not play this and says:

```
Video can't be played because the file is corrupt.
```

Yet, if I use wget to save the file I get the exact mp4 file with all bytes included - and local player plays the mp4 fine.

Capturing the HTTP packets I see that Firefox is not asking for a byte-range in the HTTP Request - yet the Blobstore response includes:

```
Content-Range: bytes 0-245778/245779\r\n
```

(which by the way is the full size of the mp4 file).

So why does Blobstore think it has to return HTTP 206?  ...and how to get it not to?

Comment: Have you tried serving the same file from somewhere that will return it with status 200? Is it the 206 or the actual file contents that are throwing FF off?